# Aeronautical equivalents of the nautical terms "port" and "starboard"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Are there any aeronautical terms for *left* and *right* sides of a plane, essentially equivalent to their nautical counterpart terms of ***port*** and ***starboard*** for the respective *left* and *right* sides of a seaworthy vessel?

Comment: Sorry, purefusion, I've just realised that because the definition of each word is in a reputable online resource (see my answer) that makes this question general reference. Please see the FAQ for more details: [Where can I find answers to basic and simple questions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#where-can-i-find-answers-to-simple-and-basic-questions) and [Why are some questions closed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#close)

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I'd never heard anyone use the terms outside of nautical references, but I did look up the Wikipedia reference for port and starboard before posting this, and somehow I totally missed the word aircraft—it's right there! Either I'm blind, or I was simply distracted by all the images of cruise ships on the page! :)

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Port* and *starboard* are used in aeronautical contexts as well as plain old nautical ones.

See these definitions:

[Starboard](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/starboard)

> **noun** — the right-hand side of or direction from a vessel or aircraft, facing forward.

[Port<sup>2</sup>](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/port)

> **noun** — the left-hand side of a vessel or aircraft, facing forward.

Comment: Ah, I guess I missed that. I don't recall having ever heard anyone use either term in reference to aircraft. Thanks for clearing this up! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing of aviation beyond the experience of a passenger, but I would assume the terms *port* and *starboard* are used in the air as on the sea. I'm prepared to be corrected by any aviators present.

**EDIT:**

The OED confirms both Dictionary.com and my intuition. Definition A of the noun *port* is

> The left side of a ship **or aircraft**, looking forward

Definition A of *starboard* is:

> The right-hand side of a ship . . . **Also used with reference to
>   aircraft**

My emphasis in both.

Comment: Also confirmed [here](http://pilotportalusa.atspace.com/aviation_dictionary_s2.html)